# Access values stored between starting and ending pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the below mentioned function in a large piece of code(in c++):

```
void startup(const char *&      start,
    const char *&   stop);
```

After this function has been called I want to access the character values i.e string stored between 'start' and 'stop'.

The way I am trying to access the same is:

```
 char *var=(c.start);
  cout<<"\n Iterating over char pointer \n";
  while(var<=(c.stop))
  {
      cout<<*var;
      var++;
  }
  cout<<"\n";
```

However, while trying to access it this way I am getting the below mentioned error:

```
  error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Can someone be kind enough to rectify the error...and help me access the character values

Comment: What is `c`? Why `startup` changes the value of its arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is replace the line:

```
char *var=(c.start);
```

with:

```
const char *var=(c.start);
```

Note that that `const` refers to the character pointed to by the pointer, not the pointer itself.  So an expression like `var++` is perfectly fine, since the pointer isn't const.

Comment: @user1355603, it makes no difference in the way you use it. It only makes a difference because C++ is preventing you from doing something wrong. If the pointer wasn't to a `const char` then you could accidentally try to modify the string. By using `const` this is not allowed.

Comment: Because `start` and `stop` were const char pointers.  You're generally not allowed to copy a pointer-to-const to a pointer-to-non-const (unless you use a cast, but you should only do that if you understand what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this conversion in the assigning statement:

```
char *pc = (char *)(c.start);
```

Comment: What I have here is based on my experience dealing with GCC C++ compiler, and the Visual C++ behaves a lot different, so you may just try.